# Scaling Horizontally for Modelling

Tags: geometry

> I have a vase, whose base can be modelled by the following equation $$y=(1.25916975182872)x^4+(-4.29578020022745)x^3+(4.37766951188496)x^2+(-0.553610482668319)x+(-1.6343566433531)$$
>   ...defined in the domain $0.1 < x < 1.3$, when rotated $2\pi$ radians about the x-axis.

I found this equation  through polynomial regression.

I would now like to scale this equation, such that each coordinate unit represents one centimetre. As you can imagine, scaling the vase vertically is not an issue. I found that $1.6501$ (the y-value for when $x = 0.1$) was, in reality, $3.95$ centimetres. Dividing $3.95$ by $1.6501$, I quickly got to the conclusion that a scale factor of $k = 2.39$ had to multiplied to the entire RHS of the function to stretch it vertically by the right amount.

The issue arose when I tried calculating the horizontal scale factor. I measured that $8.95$ coordinate units represented $20.1$ centimetres (I got this by using values for the entire vase, not just the base). But I am unsure how this ratio could be used to scale the function horizontally.

Comment: $\frac{20.1}{8.95}=2.25$. So we need to squash the graph of $y=f(x)$ (the curve generating the vase) by a factor of 2.25. To do this we can replace $x$ with $2.25x$ everywhere it appears in the polynomial.

Comment: That shrunk the polynomial closer to the y-axis rather than pushing it further out.

Comment: Oh. Then instead of replacing $x$ with $2.25x$, replace it with $\frac x{2.25}$.

Comment: How would I determine the new domain of the function? Looking at the graphs, the slopes are clearly different between the end points of the vase (0.1 and 1.3)...

Comment: Having stretched the vase by a factor of 2.25, the endpoint values can be multiplied by this same amount. Hence the vase is bounded by 0.1 * 2.25 and 1.3 * 2.25 along the x-axis.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for your time.